# Anaconda navigator freezes at " loading environments"

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

ı download the anaconda navigator 3 hours ago and  this text still appears on the screen when ı tried the open anaconda navigator.What should ı do? Please help!
[enter image description here](https:/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbSu2.png)/i.stack.imgur.com/WXV45.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/672r0.png)

anaconda navigator is not opening

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.